# Testing if an object contains a nested object with a specific property value

Tags: javascript

I want to make sure that two properties (referencing objects) `connected` and `connections` both contain at least one property, like this:

```
if ((Object.keys(layer[i1].connected).length > 0 
&& Object.keys(layer[i1].connections).length > 0) || /* other logic omitted */) {
    //do stuff
}
```

That works so far. But I realized I need to make sure not only that properties exist within `connected` and `connections` but also that those contents contain the property `active` which is equal to `true`.

So the contents need to be:

```
connections : { //at least one is true
    34 : {
        active : true 
    },
    37 : {
        active : false
    },
    38 : {
        active : false
    }
}
```

and (`&&`)

```
connected : { //at least one is true
    12 : {
        active : true
    },
    22 : {
        active : true
    }
}
```

**not**

```
connections : {
    34 : {
        active : false
    },
}
```

or

```
connected : {}
```

I'm just wondering if there's a simple, elegant way to perform this kind of check rather than the messy options I'm thinking of. **Is there an elegant way to do this?** Obviously there are many ways to do it, but I'm really interested in a one-line approach, similar to how `Object.keys` very neatly exposes the number of properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is pretty specific, so why not just make your own helper function:

```
const hasActiveProp = obj => Object.keys(obj).some(k => obj[k].active)
```

Then you can just do:

```
if(hasActiveProp(layer[i1].connected) && hasActiveProp(layer[i1].connections)){
  // do something here
}
```

---

Just to note though that in order to make your code elegant, I wouldn't focus on your specific problem, but rather why you need to perform this check. You should figure out if there is any way you can get the data in a different format so that the check becomes more intuitive.

Comment: That actually is a much more elegant check than what I had in mind. Thanks. Edit: have to award the answer to nnnnn though since his is essentially the same and was submitted first!

Comment: @Viziionary - It wouldn't bother me if you accepted this answer. It's a bit more complete in that I only suggested encapsulating the test in a function, whereas this answer actually showed the function...

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way I can think to apply your test condition is like this:

```
Object.keys(layer[i1].connections).some(p=>layer[i1].connections[p].active)
```

I don't consider that particularly elegant, but at least it is still a single expression.

I'd encapsulate that in a function so that you can just call the function twice from within your `if` condition.

Comment: By the way I couldnt think of the proper way to title what my question really is, if you'd like to edit the title to something less vague Ill happily accept the edit.

Comment: OK, well I edited the title to make it much more specific. Not sure if the new title is *elegant*, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fun way to do it in 1 line:) If you are good with regex, you can handle all the cases with 1 test, and you don't need check obj availability.

```js
var obj = {
  connections: { //at least one is true
    34: {
      active: true
    },
    37: {
      active: false
    },
    38: {
      active: false
    }
  },
  connected: { //at least one is true
    12: {
      active: true
    },
    22: {
      active: false
    }
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))

console.log(/{"active":true}/.test(JSON.stringify(obj.connections)) && /{"active":true}/.test(JSON.stringify(obj.connected)))
```